Sum involving product of binomial coefficients
Given two integers $N$ and $x$, I want to calculate (or approximate in the limit for $N>>x$) the following sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{x+1} (-1)^k\cdot2^k \binom{x+1}{k}\binom{N-k}{x}.
\end{equation}
Without the last binomial coefficient this sum can be easily evaluated by using the Binomial theorem. In this case we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{x+1} (-1)^k\cdot2^k \binom{x+1}{k}=(-1)^{x+1}.
\end{equation}
However I do not seem to find a way to compute the sum with the extra binomial coefficients.

Consider the asymptotic expansion of $$\binom{N-k}{x} \approx \frac{N^x}{x!}$$
Which, using the binomial expansion result you have provided, gives $$S\approx\frac{N^x}{x!}\cdot(-1)^{x+1}$$

$$S(x,N)=\sum_{k=0}^{x+1} (-2)^k\binom{x+1}{k}\binom{N-k}{x}$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ix t}(1+e^{it})^N\left(\frac{e^{it}-1}{e^{it}+1}\right)^{x+1}dt=\frac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x!}\frac{\partial^x}{\partial z^x},\bigg|_{z=0}(1+z)^N\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^{x+1}$$
